# Git move origin/master forward

Tags: git

How can I move origin/master forward? I created a new branch (origin/phasing) to do some development and then subsequently merged master with it. However, when I look at the log, origin/master & origin/head have got left behind while HEAD -> master is ahead by a few commits pointing at origin/phasing (see image below).

[image]

`git merge --ff-only origin/master` or `git merge origin/master` say `already up-to-date`.

Comment: `origin/master` is the remote-tracking branch that indicates the remote's state. You need to `git push master` if you want to update it.

Comment: *"I created a new branch (origin/phasing)"* -- how did you create it? If it is displayed when you run `git branch` then it is a local branch (yes, a branch name is allowed to contain `/`) and not a remote tracking branch.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your phasing commits are pushed to the origin/phasing branch, checkout the master branch, and then merge the phasing one into master